# How to recover deleted container

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I used this statement to accidentally delete by entire container.

```
block_blob_service.delete_container(container_name)
```

Is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no programmatic way to recover a deleted container. What you could do is reach out to Azure Support and they may be able to recover that data.

Comment: Does it usually get recovered?

Comment: Yes, if you don't delay raising the support ticket.

Comment: How do I generate the ticket? Let me know please :p

Comment: Go to Azure Portal, open a support ticket. Simple 

Comment: Thanks. Apologies. Freaking out a little :D